# How can I get an image texture using Random.Range in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Resources folder in Assets, and an Images folder in that Resources folder. I want to get an image from there randomly.

```
private List<string> images = new List<string>();
private int imageIndex;
public GameObject rawImage;
Texture2D myTexture;

void Start()
{
    images.Add("First");
    images.Add("Second");
    images.Add("Third");

    imageIndex = Random.Range(0, (images.Count - 1));

    myTexture = Resources.Load("Images/imageIndex") as Texture2D;
    rawImage.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myTexture; 
}
```

Name of my images in Images folder are like "0", "1", "2" so I was expecting that this works, if I use this;

```
myTexture = Resources.Load("Images/0") as Texture2D;
```

It works, also if I put the images to Resources folder directly and if I use this;

```
myTexture = Resources.Load(imageIndex) as Texture2D;
```

This also works but I need that Images folder and it should work like ("Images/imageIndex"). Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're asking, but this code:

```
imageIndex = Random.Range(0, (images.Count - 1));

myTexture = Resources.Load("Images/imageIndex") as Texture2D;
```

Will attempt to find an image literally named "imageIndex" in your `Resources/Images` folder. Unless you have a file named "imageIndex", that's not going to work.

Instead, substitute the *value* of your `imageIndex` variable into the string passed to `Resources.Load()`, like so:

```
var imagePath = $"Images/{imageIndex}";
myTexture = Resources.Load(imagePath);
```

Note the '$' and `{..}` in the string, which will convert `imageIndex` from an integer to a string and insert it in place of `{imageIndex}`.

Another note: the parameters for the `int` version of `Random.Range()` are

```
public static int Range(int minInclusive, int maxExclusive);
```

So, your call should really be

```
imageIndex = Random.Range(0,images.Count);
```

... without the `-1`. You could skip the `images` collection and just do this:

```
var imageIndex = Random.Range(0,3); // returns 0, 1 or 2.
var imageFilename = $"Images/{imageIndex}";
myTexture = Resources.Load(imageFilename);
```

Comment: I didn't know the usage of $"Images/{imageIndex}", now it works without any problem. Thanks for the answer also thanks for the information about the Random.Range parameters

Comment: @acemi You could also do `imageFilename = "Images/" + imageIndex.ToString();` The other way is just shorthand for the same thing.

Comment: Ahh I used ("Images/imageIndex.ToString()"); but it didn't work, I couldn't think the separate "Images" and Index

Comment: @acemi anything you put inside the quotes is going to be literal text. If you want to call the method `.ToString()`, it has to be in `{}` or *outside of the quotes*. This is pretty basic C# stuff.